# Obtener data JSON

Tags: php, jquery

Saludos. Necesito obtener los registros de una fila en especifico, mediante ajax estoy enviando el id hacia php y obtengo la fila, pero no estoy pudiendo manipular los datos para luego asignarlos a elementos html. En donde estara el error?

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_project').on('change', function() 
    {
    var id_project = $('#id_project').val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "ff.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{id_project},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data)
        {
            var datos = data.nb_informacion_general_localizacion;
            alert(datos);
        },
    })
});
});
```

PHP

```
$id_project = $_POST['id_project'];
$sql = "bla bla bla";
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['id_project'];
  echo $row['nb_informacion_general_localizacion'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás devolviendo cada variable por separado, por lo tanto, al realizar:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['id_project'];
  echo $row['nb_informacion_general_localizacion'];
}
```

estarás enviando solamente la primera respuesta (`id_project`) ya que el AJAX está esperando a la primera respuesta que le llegue.

Para poder solventar esto te recomiendo que englobes la información dentro de un array y lo codifiques como JSON. De esta manera, podrás acceder a los datos mucho más fácilmente desde tu llamada AJAX.

Tu código PHP quedaría así:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $fila['id_project'] = $row['id_project'];
   $fila['nb_informacion_general_localizacion'] = $row['nb_informacion_general_localizacion'];
}

echo json_encode($fila);
```

**IMPORTANTE:**

- Tendrás que cambiar el `dataType` de tu función AJAX a `json`.
- Tendrás que añadir la cabecera `header("Content-type: application/json");` al inicio de tu fichero PHP.

Comment: hola francisco, y la sintaxis para manipularlo en ajax como seria?

Comment: @osmelg Puedes imprimir la variable `data` para ver que te devuelve pero en principio deberías poder acceder a los datos simplemente usando `data.id_project` y `data.nb_informacion_general_localizacion`.

Comment: justamente lo estaba probando de esa manera, alert(data) y no trae la fila seleccionada, el query finaliza en WHERE id_project='".$id_project."'

Comment: otro detalle que esta dando tu codigo es que la estructura del resultado es {,} y pienso que deberia ser [{:]]

Comment: @osmelg Ahí si no veo mal, creo que estás usando comillas simples con comillas dobles `'"`, los ID suelen ser autonumericos, por lo que en teoría no sería necesario el uso de comillas simples. En cuanto a lo del formato `{,}` es porque en este caso al devolver un solo elemento lo trata como objeto (al pasarlo a JSON). En caso de que fueran más de una línea las que tuvieras que devolver tendrías que indicar el índice dónde quieres que se agreguen. Ej:  `$fila[$id]['id_project'] = $row['id_project'];`

Comment: correcto, tienes razon. Una ultima consulta, cuando intento hacer un data.id_project o cualquier otro registro que necesite, me trae undefined

Comment: En la petición Ajax debería cambiar el dataType a json y en PHP hacer echo de los datos agrupados y codificados en JSON con json_encode. Pero antes del echo debe establecer el header con el content-type json.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón, se me había pasado mencionar ambos términos. Ahora edito la respuesta para que se quede totalmente actualizada.